How to make Git File History use my local date format
For some reason, the "Git File History" command is showing dates in US format, although my Mac is set to use Australian date format.
How can I get it to respect my system-wide date format?

I can't see where any dates are shown (mine's all "Over a month ago", "Over 3 months ago", etc). Can you share a screenshot?

I tried to, and StackOverflow complained that the post was too image-heavy.

Ugh, can you add it as an image link? This is for the GitLens extension yeah?


Open Settings (⌘,)
Search for "gitlens default date"

You should find two relevant settings

Gitlens: Default Date Format
Gitlens: Default Date Locale

I'd say the latter is more important and you'll want to set it to system or en-AU if that's not working for whatever reason.

These configuration values can be edited in your settings.json.
